# Profile in wordpress need phone validation

Tags: wordpress, phone, validation

I have this profile form made  https://emptyhometax.org/civicrm/profile/create/?gid=2&reset=1
and want to make it so phone can only be enter in one way through validation 123-456-7890. I don't want people to be able to leave our a number or put in an extra one.

Comment: we have done work on phone validation for a couple of clients but as civi is international there is no approach that will suit all countries/situations.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this using caldera form with Civi integration? Or afform extension in Civi?

Comment: probably but i thought caldera forms was retiring at the end of the year isn't there a way to do this through civiCRM   https://calderaforms.com/2021/03/the-future-of-caldera-forms/#:~:text=Caldera%20Forms%20%26%20add%2Dons%20will,retired%20on%2031%20Dec%202021.